# How to import Media Queries with Scss?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I know that I can import a css modules into my main css file with the condition that it fulfill media queries requirements typing the condition in the `@import` rule. But the moment I try to do the same using a scss file instead of css it does nothing. How can I use media queries in Scss the same way I do in CSS?

This is how my code in css looks like:

#### styles.css

```
@import 'blue.css' (min-height: 300px);
@import 'red.css' (min-height: 400px);
```

#### blue.css

```
.square{
  background:blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

#### red.css

```
.square{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But as soon as I change the format from css to scss it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: There is no way to perform media query imports in SCSS.

The `@import` rule works differently in SCSS vs CSS.

Everything CSS is valid SCSS...except for the `@import` statement.

In SCSS, the import statement just requires the path to the file and the file name. If you're importing files for the purposes of combining them into one CSS file, you need to name those files starting with an underscore.

If you have something like this structure, where the breakpoint file is called "_breakpoint.scss":

/root/scss/main.scss

/root/scss/modules/_breakpoint.scss

Then you'll need to write your import statement this way:

```
@import "modules/breakpoint";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "small";

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  @import "medium";
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  @import "large";
}
```